# How to convert $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI into PATH

Tags: bash, path, uri

I need to convert $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI with non-latin symbols to PATH

eg
`/home/shara/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9<br>%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB/testdir`
to
`/home/shara/Рабочий стол/testdir`

How to do this?

Comment: For future readers: I found [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/76266/81372) over at askubuntu to work great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<br>` in the middle is just an accident, something like this:

```
in="/home/shara/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB/testdir"
eval out=\$\'${in//%/\\x}\'
```

Note, this does no correction for your locale, it only replaces the %XX escapes with the matching raw byte. You can use `iconv` if necessary. Also, if a raw % is escaped as `%%` instead of `%25` (this is not mentioned in your question) or if the input may contain backslashes, you will need to account for those too.

Comment: It's safer to avoid `eval`: `out=$(printf "${in//%/\\x}")` and you don't have to do all that escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with this

```
selected_files=($NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS)
for dir in "${selected_files[@]}" ; do
    base=$(readlink -f "$(dirname "$dir")")
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The following, adapted from [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187256/176466) (in this case we don't need to replace '+' with ' '), will work with any POSIX shell, not just bash, (e.g. dash):

```
current_nautilus_path=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI" | sed -e 's/%/\\x/g' -e 's_^file://__' | xargs -0 printf "%b")
```

Alternatively, if bashisms are OK, but you don't want to call any external programs, a slight modification of [Jester's/Dennis Williamson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530549/6598435) will give you the path without the "file:" prefix:

```
percent_decoded_uri=$(printf "${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI//%/\\x}")
current_nautilus_path=${percent_decoded_uri#file://}
```

Finally, if calling python from within the script does not bother you, I strongly recommend the [solution from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/76266/480880), suggested by Glutanimate, as it provides support for arbitrary gvfs protocols (e.g. sftp) for free:

```
current_nautilus_path=$(python -c 'import gio,sys; print(gio.File(sys.argv[1]).get_path())' "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI")
```